# How to solve this with json_encode(php array from database) result

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Hi i have a table with name `Users` that have these columns:

```
UserId INT
DisplayName VARCHAR(50)
Username VARCHAR(50)
Password VARCHAR(50)
```

i get records from this table with mysqli (`mysqli_query`,`mysqli_fetch_array`) like this:

```
$users=array();
while($user=mysqli_fetch_array($result)
$users=array("User"=>$user);
echo json_encode(array("Users"=>$users));
```

and the result of json_encode is:

```
{"users":{
    "user":{
        "0":"1",
        "UserId":"1",
        "1":"name",
        "DisplayName":"name",
        "2":"usernameTest",
        "Username":"usernameTest",
        "3":"passwordTest",
        "Password":"passwordTest"
    }
}}
```

But must be:

```
{"users":{
    "user":{
        "UserId":"1",
        "DisplayName":"name",
        "Username":"usernameTest",
        "Password":"passwordTest"
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either tell `mysql_fetch_array` to fetch an associative array with `MYSQLI_ASSOC`:

```
$user = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Or use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` that fetches an associative array:

```
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php):

```
$users=array();
while($user=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
  $users=array("User"=>$user);
echo json_encode(array("Users"=>$users));
```

Btw your code seems a little off. Are your sure you only want to have a single user in this format returned?